# How to remove border of table in HTML code

Tags: html

I have some HTML code and would like to remove the outer borders of a `<table>`

```
<table class="table1">
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4" class="tableheader"><center>Tarieventabel 2019</center></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="description"></td>
        <td class="description"><b><center>Van</center></b></td>
        <td class="description"><b><center>Tot</center></b></td>
        <td class="description"><b><center>Prijs</center></b></td>
```

Comment: need to see your CSS. probably just need to remove the parameter `border` from your CSS

Comment: Apply style `border:none` and if you want single line use `border-collapse:collapse`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve with using css.

```
<table class="borderNone" style="border:none;">
    <tr>
        <tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" class="tableheader">
                    <center>Tarieventabel 2019</center>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="description"></td>
                <td class="description"><b><center>Van</center></b></td>
                <td class="description"><b><center>Tot</center></b></td>
                <td class="description"><b><center>Prijs</center></b></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Or using css classes

```
.borderNone{ border: none;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will try it now hope it works :D Thank you :)

Comment: This seems to be working only it looks like the table has no spaces it is now crampt next to each other could it be that I need to add more breaks?

Comment: if you want more break with <td> tags also you can use width. Like this 
<td width="70%">January</td>
    <td width="30%">$100</td>